# Does DateTime.Now always return a 24 hour format by default?

Tags: c#, datetime

Currently it is evening and couldn't actually test it with morning hours like 7 in the morning.
but a code like this:

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.Now;
string str = dt.ToString("HH:mm");
```

So my question is can I be sure that it is always returning time in format like `"07:35"` and not `"7:35"` ?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zdtaw1bw(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`DateTime.Now` returns time without formatting. Format applied in the `ToString("HH:mm")` method. And yes, this format is 24-hour.

Answer (score 2):

Yes because the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#HH_Specifier) says:

> [`The "HH" Custom Format Specifier`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#HH_Specifier): The "HH" custom format specifier (plus any number of additional "H" specifiers) represents the hour as a number from 00 through 23; that is, the hour is represented by a zero-based 24-hour clock that counts the hours since midnight. **A single-digit hour is formatted with a leading zero.**

Answer (score 1):

You could test with

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.Now;
string str = dt.ToString("HH:mm");
Console.WriteLine(str);
DateTime t = new DateTime(2014,3,27,7,5,0);
str = t.ToString("H:mm");
Console.WriteLine(str);
```

The `HH` format return always the hour formatted with two digits adding a leading zero when the hour is less than 10, the `H` format returns the hours formatted with exactly the digits present in the hour part.

Answer (score 1):

You can create an instance of DateTime with desired date and time values using to test various time setting and formats :

```
var dt = new DateTime(2014, 1, 1, 7, 35, 0);
string str = dt.ToString("HH:mm");
```